# Any alternatives to CachingHttpClient for Android?

Tags: android, apache, http, caching

I want to enable HttpCaching for my Android app, so I'm looking for a library project to depend upon. [CachingHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient-cache/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/cache/CachingHttpClient.html) looks nice, but uses Apache HttpClient 4.1 and Android only includes 4.0

So, are there any other good http-cache projects for java that are usable on Android?

Comment: Have you looked at implementing a cache your self? I don't know what type of caching you're looking for, if its just the response or the entire HTML that's in a WebView. 

For the WebView way you can intercept the url being loaded and send cached HTML to it.

If its just the responses, why not quickly write a caching class that decides when to use cached data and when to invalidate and pass through to the HttpClient.

Comment: I do not use a webview, I want to make my REST API access more data efficient. You are probably right, I will end up righting a cache handling class. But I am pretty sure some one else already has :-B And even if the problem is limited I am sure there is an existing, tested solution...

Comment: Have a look at GSON, it will serialize your objects so you can store and retrieve them easily from say, Android's Shared Preferences.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Its what we do when we need to store persistent serialized data on Android.

Comment: GSON is nice but is not what I'm looking for. I am talking about the stuff described here http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html

Comment: Why not just use HttpClient 4.1 directly?  I'm using it without problem.