# Are there any HttpCahce client libraries for Java?

Tags: java, android, http, caching, etag

I have already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941370/any-alternatives-to-cachinghttpclient-for-android/7954174#7954174) about this for android, but I will broaden the question to include java in general... Are there any libraries for implementing a Http cache? I want to download my images more efficiently, honoring If-Modified-Since, etags, etc.

I'm sure there is a library to which one can pass the url of the image and let the lib handle all redirects or fetch the locally stored content in a cache?

BR // Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) and also this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html). Maybe they help? Also look at a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456987/httpclient-4-how-to-capture-last-redirect-url).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! This looks like something good, I will try it as soon as I get my hands on that Ice Cream!